# Get table cell data into UI button action?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I want to create registration page or login page through `tableView`. I created a custom dynamic cell, and passed the value through array and then I created button outside the `tableView`. I want to get the data in button action; e.g., if the user forgot to fill one field then, when the button is pressed, the `UIAlertView` should  show message to fill all fields. My question is how can I get data from the customized cell's value table into the Button?

Comment: Have you used Model to store data and to send data whether in webservice or database...?

Comment: This is a very vague question. What problems are you specifically facing? You should have a controller object that is in charge of both the table and the button. This controller should do the checking and flag alerts.

Comment: @TheMall:sorry did not use model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom cells or can manage UITableviewCell by tags.

On Your button tap event, get Tableviewcells one by one and validate the textbox values with in cell.
To identify cells You can check class of cell and tag for that cell.
Remember in cellForRowAtIndexPath you must assign tag value to cell.
Like,

```
[cell setTag:indexPath.row];
```

For easy understanding you can also define enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UserLogin) {

UserLoginName                          = 0,
UserLoginEmailId                       = 1,
UserLoginPassword                      = 2, };
```

**EDIT :**

```
#define TEXTFIELD_TAG 501
```

Also set tag for UITextField in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    [cell.textField setTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];
```

To get value of text  from text field loop through cells.

```
NSString *strUserName, *strEmailId, *strPassword;
// Loop upto total cells in tableview or counts of your datasource. depends on your implementation.
for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iPath];
    UserLogin loginState = cell.tag;
    switch (loginState) {
        case UserLoginName: {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];
            strUserName = [textField text];
            break;
        }
        case UserLoginEmailId: {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];
            strEmailId = [textField text];
            break;
        }
        case UserLoginPassword: {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];
            strPassword = [textField text];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**// Process string values for valdation**

There are manyways to do that. You can choose the best for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile developemnt you should strictly follow MVC. Create a model class of User and set its property like username, password. As these all will be set through textfield, so you can populate your user object in textFieldDidEndEditing. From your user object you can add text of user properties to any button just like that.
`    // user class
    @interface User : NSObject

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_fname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_lname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_email;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_phone;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_state;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_city;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * user_username;

@end

//Than create an object of user in your model class for sign-up or sign-in
User *user = [[User alloc] init]; // object created

// textfield delegate method
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if (textField == usernameTF) {
  user.user_username = textField.text;
}
else if (textField == passwordTF) {
  user.user_password = textField.text;
}
  return YES;
}
```

`

you have data in your user object and you can use its property(require data) where  you want.